# How can I create an alias/shorcut to sudo/root an app permanently?

Tags: shortcut, sudo, alias, root

I would like to have an alias to run an app as root always. I am trying to save time and not go through the terminal commands.

Thanks!

Comment: How secure does this need to be?  If you do not need to worry about security this will make it easier.

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to run as root? Desktop applications should never be run as root.

Comment: Doesnt need to be secure at all. The app Id like to run is Blender.